# Rank of system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra

I am doing rank of matrices. While solving the system of linear homogeneous equations I obtained the same rank of a certain system as solved in book but there used some different row operations than what I used.Is it possible to obtain same rank using two different row operation?? Should both method be correct.

Comment: Yes. If you used correct row operations then you would get the same rank no matter in what order or way you have done it. Because each row operation does not change rank, you had the same rank all along

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason we are *allowed* to use row operations at all to find the rank of a matrix is that *no row operation changes the rank* (provided it's carried out correctly). You can do whatever row operations you want, and the rank of the resulting matrix will be the same as the rank of the matrix you started with.

The reason we *actually* use row operations to find the rank of a matrix is because it is a relatively easy way to find another matrix with the same rank, but where the rank is more easily seen. Exactly how you go about finding such a matrix, and which matrix you actually end up with, is entirely up to you, and any derivations will necessarily give the same answer (again, provided there are no mistakes during calculations).

Comment: @Arthur..Got it. Thankyou.